# How to render images in Nuxt3 preview using the NuxtImg component when images are in the assets/images folder?

Tags: nuxt3

My nuxt3 app is rendering images well in development but after running build and then running preview the images are not showing. The images are located in the assets/images folder.

Here is my nuxt.config.ts

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: false },
  modules: [
    "@vueuse/nuxt",
    "@nuxt/image",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss",
    "@formkit/auto-animate/nuxt",
    "nuxt-swiper",
    "@vee-validate/nuxt",
  ],
  image: { dir: "assets/images" },
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      googleMapsApiKey: process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
    },
  },
});
```

I am using images like this

```html
<NuxtImg src="/R1.jpg" />
```

Comment: Tried with `~/R1.jpg`?